# rails 3.1.0 ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I made a basic rails app with a simple pages controller with an index function and when I load the page I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Demo</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__43625033_88530400'
```

Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

Comment: bundle exec rake assets:precompile seems to fix it, but why doesn't it just work?

Comment: I have the same problem in production, even after run bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Answer (score 313, accepted):

By default Rails assumes that you have your files precompiled in the production environment, if you want use live compiling (compile your assets during runtime) in production you must set the **config.assets.compile to true**.

```
# config/environments/production.rb
...
config.assets.compile = true
...
```

You can use this option to fallback to Sprockets when you are using precompiled assets but there are any missing precompiled files.

If `config.assets.compile` option is set to false and there are missing precompiled files you will get an "AssetNoPrecompiledError" indicating the name of the missing file.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but on Heroku. Issuing a "rake assets:precompile" remotely doesn't work. Do I need anything else like setting any paths or something? Thanks

Comment: You might want to try what this article says:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar

(I haven't tried it myself yet)

Comment: Just to be clear, the config.assets.compile option is in config/environments/production.rb (if you are working in production).  And if you want to be able to do live/lazy compile in production, you also need to enable the lazy compile in application.rb.

Comment: Activating runtime compilation is not the solution, because of the performance hit we take. The solution is to fix the core problem which is preventing asset precompilation from occurring.

Comment: I precompiled the assets using RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile. Why Am I getting this error and needed to set this flag too?

Comment: Thank you so much it took me two days to find the cause and solution to my issue!

Comment: @Tony, because you probably ask for something other than application.css/js/image file, and you didn't register it on `application.rb`. Add to/edit `application.rb`: `config.assets.precompile += %w( first.css second.js )`. Now these files will compile as well. Don't add all files if you use them only in sprockets `require`, but only if you include them with `<link>`/`<script>`

Comment: Also can use `render :layout => false` in your action :D

Comment: I could not agree more with @DavidTuite comment. Here's the solution that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425929/rails-3-1-strategy-for-pre-compiling-controller-specific-js-assets

Answer (score 202):

You will get better performance in production if you set config.assets.compile to false in production.rb and precompile your assets.  You can precompile with this rake task:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

If you are using Capistrano, version 2.8.0 has a recipe to handle this at deploy time.  For more info, see the "In Production" section of the Asset Pipeline Guide: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: I can't believe how hard it was to find out how to do this.

Comment: This seems like the clearly better option: setting live compile to true "uses more memory, performs more poorly than the default and is not recommended." 

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#live-compilation

Comment: `rake -T` or `bundle exec rake -T` is your friend.

Comment: Why use bundle exec rake assets:precompile over rake assets:precompile?

Comment: @Underworld Bundler is a tool for managing gem dependencies in a ruby app and it is built into Rails 3.  If you are using bundler, running `bundle exec rake ...` will ensure that you are loading the right rake and associated dependencies for your app.  If you are not using bundler, you would just run `rake ...`.

Comment: I found I had to uncomment this `Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)` in config/application.rb for this to work also

Comment: If you're going to run the above command, make sure that you're already set your environment to production mode, or prefix the command with 
    RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: And don't forget to restart your server after precompiling the assets (nginx for example).

Comment: you might have to run this as a root user.

Answer (score 31):

OK - I had the same problem.  I didn't want to use "config.assets.compile = true" - I had to add all of my .css files to the list in config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( carts.css )
```

Then I had to create (and later delete) tmp/restart.txt

I consistently used the stylesheet_link_tag helper, so I found all the extra css files I needed to add with:

```
find . \( -type f -o -type l \) -exec grep stylesheet_link_tag {} /dev/null \;
```

Comment: If you use media queries and different css files for different resolutions, this is the best way to go.

Comment: I have to include all my css files in array? What if I have 40 css files?

Answer (score 30):

A quick fix for capistrano user is to put this line to Capfile

```
# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
load 'deploy/assets'
```

Answer (score 11):

For all those who are reading this but do not have problem with `application.css` and instead with their custom CSS classes e.g. `admin.css`, `base.css` etc.

Solution is to use as mentioned

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

And in stylesheets references just reference `application.css`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
```

Since assets pipeline will precompile all of your stylesheets in application.css. This also happens in development so using any other references is wrong when using assets pipeline.

Answer (score 8):

I was having the exact same error in my development environment. In the end all I needed to do in order to fix it was to add:

```
config.assets.manifest = Rails.root.join("public/assets")
```

to my config/environments/development.rb file and it fixed it. My final config in development related to assets looks like:

```
config.assets.compress = false  
config.assets.precompile += %w[bootstrap-alerts.js] #Lots of other space separated files
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.manifest = Rails.root.join("public/assets")
config.assets.debug = true
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Maybe it was a problem with my version of Rails (3.1.3)? Anyway, I could tell my assets had been successfully precompiled to public/assets and their filenames had the same SHAs as listed in manifest.yml. For some reason, Rails was no longer looking for assets in the right place, even though my setup had always worked fine previously. This change fixed that.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I was trying to test some things in development mode and I was surprised that it was saying "application.css isn't precompiled" even though I had already precompiled assets and public/assets/application.css was present in the directory. Surprised they don't set config.assets.manifest for you automatically in development like they do in production..

Answer (score 5):

I also had this issue, where trying to run in production without precompiling it would still throw not-precompiled errors. I had to change which line was commented application.rb:

```
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
```

Comment: Just want to clarify for anyone coming across this later, the code you need to change above is located in `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 4):

Here's the quick fix:

If you're using capistrano do this add this to your deploy.rb:

```
after 'deploy:update_code' do
  run "cd #{release_path}; RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile"
end
```

cap deploy

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error message today and wanted to post the resolution to my particular my case.  It turns out that my problem was that one of my css files was missing a closing brace and this was causing the file to not be compiled.  It may be harder to notice this if you have an automated process that sets everything up (including the asset precompile) for your production environment.

Answer (score 1):

After all else failed...

My solution was to change the layout file from

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "reset-min", 'application'
```

to

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
```

And it worked! (You can put the reset file inside the manifest.)

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to fix this up on Heroku: Make sure your Rakefile is committed and pushed.

Answer (score 0):

On heroku server (readonly filesystem), 
If you want runtime compilation of css (its not recommended but you can do it), make sure you have done settings like below -

```
# inside config/application.rb
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.prefix = Rails.root.join('tmp/assets').to_s

# If you are using sass then keep gem outside of asset group
 gem 'sass-rails',   '3.1.4'

# inside config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.compile = true
```

Answer (score 0):

if you think you followed everything good but still unlucky, just make sure you/capistrano run touch tmp/restart.txt or equivalent at the end. I was in the unlucky list but now :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a `syntax error` in the css you are using.

Run this command

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development --trace
```

It will give the exception, fixed that and you are all done.

Thanks