# Rails 3.1 strategy for pre-compiling controller specific JS assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

In order to keep controller specific JavaScript logic out of the standard `application.js` and only have it included by the relevant controller, I'm putting it in its own .js file and including it based on the controller name from the layout like such:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", params[:controller] %>
```

That works just fine, but when I deploy the app to production (I'm using Capistrano and have a pre-compile task set up), the asset pipeline doesn't precompile any of the controller specific JS files. I presume this is because my actual JavaScript file isn't referenced by require directives in application.js.

How do I deal with this without moving my controller specific JS back to application.js, or explicitly referencing it from application.js?

Is there some way to tell the asset pipeline to pre-compile an additional list files? How could I manually pre-compile a specific file on production?

**Update**

As it [turns out](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), you can specify individual files here in your `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( achievements.js )
```

...or I just went ahead and capriciously added it for every JavaScript file:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js )
```

Comment: this should really be automatic!

Comment: Its worth noting here that adding scss/coffee files to the precomile list will NOT WORK! (And throw no error, either!).  You must name only with the .js/css extension.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to precompile the js|css **only found in the root of assets/javascripts and assets/stylesheets directories** (and not their tree hierarchy), you can put this in environment files :

```
  Dir.chdir "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/javascripts"
  a = Dir.glob("*.{js,coffee,erb}")
  Dir.chdir "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets"
  b = Dir.glob("*.{css,erb}")
  config.assets.precompile +=  a.concat(b)
  Dir.chdir Rails.root
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you and james_schorr are not really talking about the same thing.
You need to add the files other than application.js to config.assets.precompile. His answer was more about the directory structure you could/should adopt, if I'm not mistaken.

If I wanted to have controller specific, I would do:

```
/assets
    /javascripts
        /users
            login.js
            profile.js
        /blogs
        /posts
        users.js
        blogs.js
        posts.js
```

And for instance, `users.js` would be:

```
*= require_tree ./users
```

That way, you can stay organized (have a lot of js files per controller), but in prod, they will all be included in one file.

Still need that in your config:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js )
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I do:

directory structure:

```
app/assets/javascripts/sessions/multiple.js
app/assets/application-sessions.js
```

application-sessions.js just has:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ./sessions
```

Then in your view, do

```
<% if @current_controller == 'whatever' %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "application-sessions" %>
 <% else %>
   ….
 <% end %>
```

FYI, @current_controller = controller_name in my application_controller.rb methods, called with a before_filter.

Comment: That looks like a solution although a little more complex than I ended up doing in my update. I hope there's no unintended side effects to my solution.

Comment: I think that your way is fine.  The one that I listed will allow you to only include the js files that you want depending upon the "area" of your code.  That way, you're not loading more than what's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am having same issue here, it's an headache to me.

Including *.js is a little too much, I don't want every files to be compiled into separated files, some of them suppose to be merged together.

My idea is, store the controller specific files into a sub directory, such as "controllers", and then only include controllers/*.js or css files for precompile.

Not sure if it work or not, I will try it out, anyway, it might be a useful hint.