# Why is Heroku returning 'devise/sessions.js isn't precompiled'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm deploying a Rails 3.2 app to Heroku. I'm precompiling assets locally as per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar.

But I'm getting

```
ActionView::Template::Error (devise/sessions.js isn't precompiled):
```

Has anyone else encountered this?

What is the correct way to ensure Devise javascripts are precomiled.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi sethvargo. yes I'm on Cedar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for all the suggestions. After a bit of thinking, I realize that the issue was down to how the app was configured to call controller-specific javascript. IN case anyone else runs into this issue, here's what I did.

I had been loading controller-specific .js via the following tag in the layout file.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", params[:controller] %>
```

Problem is, this fails if a particular cotroller.js file does not exist. In my case, the login page failed as I had not created a devise/sessions.js file.

I could have created this file, but I felt this was a messy approach. I don't like the idea of having a lot of empty files lying around.

Instead I am explicitly calling controller-specific javascripts from the view

```
<% javascript 'controller.js' %>
```

Using the following helper in application_helpers

```
def javascript(*files)
    content_for(:head) { javascript_include_tag(*files) }
end
```

Seems to be working fine so far.

Thanks again for the suggestions.

Comment: For those interested in taking the approach of adding a js file, you can create a `devise` folder in `app/assets/javascripts`, then put the `sessions.js` file in there. Handy if you want to fancy-up the sign in page. NB: You need to list assets accessed individually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425929/rails-3-1-strategy-for-pre-compiling-controller-specific-js-assets

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the answer I've been looking for for hours!

Answer (score 5):

My solution:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", controller_name if controller_name != "sessions" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try running `rake assets:precompile`.

---

Try adding this to your config/environments/production.rb :

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )
```

Or specify your file.

Comment: Hi Justin D. I appreciate your answer, thanks a lot. This should have worked (would have worked, if I'd created the necessary .js file), but after thinking about this issue overnight, I realize the problem was due to how I was calling controller specific javascripts. I've added an answer to help others that may encounter a similar issue.