# Heroku app doesn't work when create with the heroku CLI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, heroku

I did `heroku create` and pushed a working rails app to the server.

Everything seems fine, but when I go to [the webpage](http://floating-water-2213.heroku.com/) I get an error. I even tried pushing up the same code for another heroku app I have that works, and I get the same error.

Normally I use Facebook to create the heroku app and it works fine. Is there something else I need to do besides `heroku create`?

Comment: I don't see an error when I follow your link; it would have been helpful for you to include the error text here.

Comment: The error's not there because I was able to fix it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a number of things that could be wrong. Your best bet is to check the logs:

```
heroku logs -t
```

While that's up, hit the site and see what the logs say. Did you remember to migrate (`heroku run rake db:migrate`)?

Comment: I think I already ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` because when I did it again it gave an error saying a relation already exists. When I did `heroku logs -t` I saw an error saying "ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):"

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275636/rails-3-1-0-actionviewtemplateerrror-application-css-isnt-precompiled