# Rails 500 Error: application.css isn't precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, precompiled

I've got Rails running on Passenger with Apache on an Ubuntu linux box (ve) Server from Mediatemple. My app is giving me a 500 error (a Rails error, not an Apache error) when I try to load any page: http://www.mvngmtns.com

I saw an article about changing this line in config/environments/production.rb:

```
    config.assets.compile = true
```

But this didn't solve my problem. Can anyone help?

My development.log:

```
Started GET "/" for 72.225.170.239 at 2012-06-29 15:28:43 -0700
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Rendered application/_logo.html.erb (0.6ms)
Rendered application/_navbar.html.erb (1.4ms)
Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
2: <html>
3: <head>
4:   <title>Moving Mountains<%= get_title %></title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8:
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2841110860658336572_129641540'
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:6:in `index'
```

As requested, ran

```
    rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
    touch /tmp/restart.txt
```

but still the same error. Here's what the trace said:

```
newguy@mvngmtns:/var/www/movingmountains$ rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
** Invoke assets:precompile:nondigest (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:non digest
```

I still have the same "500 - We're sorry, but something went wrong" in the browser, and cache: [GET /] miss in the apache log file.

Answer (score 6):

After setting

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

you should also run:

```
 rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

See: [rails 3.1.0 ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275636/rails-3-1-0-actionviewtemplateerrror-application-css-isnt-precompiled)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know details on Mediatemple, but perhaps you need to precompile your assets before deploying:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Hi Matchu, I tried this also, but nothing changed. Here's the line it gave me: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets

Comment: did you add the results to git repo?

Comment: I actually just ssh'ed in and ran the command in the project directory

Answer (score 2):

A couple things:

1. check that the stylesheet actually gets compiled - it will be something like `public/assets/application-XXX.css`
2. Passenger looks for `APP_DIR/tmp/restart.txt`, not `/tmp/restart.txt`, so make sure you `touch` the file in the right place