# ruby on rails tutorial, creating pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Folks,
  Trying to learn ruby on rails...  following the tutorial, and after doing the foll

```
rails generate controller Pages home contact
```

Following shows up in the log/production

```
Started GET "/pages/home" for 24.18.129.38 at 2013-01-20 10:32:17 +0000
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
2: <html>
3: <head>
4:   <title>FirstApp</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2607526346352188026_23275800'


Started GET "/pages/contact" for 24.18.129.38 at 2013-01-20 10:32:21 +0000
Processing by PagesController#contact as HTML
Rendered pages/contact.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
2: <html>
3: <head>
4:   <title>FirstApp</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2607526346352188026_23275800'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275636/rails-3-1-0-actionviewtemplateerrror-application-css-isnt-precompiled

Answer (score 1):

```
# config/environments/production.rb
...
config.assets.compile = true
...
```