# Rails No route matches [GET] "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Rails application name is Card. I have modified the routes and removed the index.html from public directory. Still I see `The page you were looking for doesn't exist.` when I visit my home page. Rake routes displays the root route correctly.

I am using Passenger with Apache.

```
root@emaillenin:/var/emaillenin/rails/card# cat config/routes.rb
Card::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => "home#index"
end
root@emaillenin:/var/emaillenin/rails/card# ls public/
404.html  422.html  500.html  favicon.ico  robots.txt
root@emaillenin:/var/emaillenin/rails/card# rake routes
root  / home#index
root@emaillenin:/var/emaillenin/rails/card# ls app/controllers/
application_controller.rb  home_controller.rb
root@emaillenin:/var/emaillenin/rails/card# cat app/controllers/home_controller.rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
root@emaillenin:/var/emaillenin/rails/card# cat app/views/home/index.html.erb
<h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>
<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
root@emaillenin:/var/emaillenin/rails/card# bundle exec rake assets:precompile
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
root@emaillenin:/var/emaillenin/rails/card# cat config/environments/production.rb | grep config.assets.compile
  config.assets.compile = true
root@emaillenin:/var/emaillenin/rails/card#
```

This is what I see in the Apache error log: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):`

When I do `rails server` and access my homepage via 3000 port, I see an error page - http://pastebin.com/1eEU3egt

Even after executing `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` I see the same error page.

Even after changing config.assets.compile to true results in the same error.

Any way to crack down this issue?

Comment: does it work correctly in development using webrick?

Comment: what's your app/views/home/index.html look like?

Comment: @MikeCampbell Update question. I see an error page when I try via webrick

Comment: @twairball Updated question. I cant find index.html. Pasted output of index.html.erb

Answer (score 2):

From another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275636/rails-3-1-0-actionviewtemplateerror-application-css-isnt-precompiled) :

By default Rails assumes that you have your files precompiled in the production environment, if you want use live compiling (compile your assets during runtime) in production you must set the **config.assets.compile to true**.

```
# config/environments/production.rb
...
config.assets.compile = true
...
```

You can use this option to fallback to Sprockets when you are using precompiled assets but there are any missing precompiled files.

If `config.assets.compile` option is set to false and there are missing precompiled files you will get an "AssetNoPrecompiledError" indicating the name of the missing file.