# Can't run Rails app on Heroku: ActionView::Template::Error ("fontawesome.less" wasn't found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm using `twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.2.7`
`Rails-3.2.11`
`sass-rails- 3.2.3`

Running application returns back:

`ActionView::Template::Error ("fontawesome.less" wasn't found....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I downgraded `twitter-bootstrap-rails` to version `2.2.6` :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it in `config.assets.precompile` (config/environments/production.rb)

Answer (score 1):

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7278355/600953

By default Rails assumes that you have your files precompiled in the production environment, if you want use live compiling (compile your assets during runtime) in production you must set the config.assets.compile to true.

```
# config/environments/production.rb
...
config.assets.compile = true
```

You can use this option to fallback to Sprockets when you are using precompiled assets but there are any missing precompiled files.

If `config.assets.compile` option is set to false and there are missing precompiled files you will get an "AssetNoPrecompiledError" indicating the name of the missing file.

Comment: Sorry guys, however downgrading twitter-bootstrap-rails gem is helped me a lot