# ActionView::Template::Error (statics.js isn't precompiled)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, precompile

My development and test servers are working fine, but I am having trouble with the production server. Sequence:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
sudo httpd service restart
```

When I try to go to my production server from a browser, I get the dreaded:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong
```

Looking at production.log, I see:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (statics.css isn't precompiled)
```

So, I added the following to config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['statics.css']
```

Still got the error screen, now the production log says:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (statics.js isn't precompiled)
```

So, I added the following to config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['statics.js']
```

I precompiled assets and restarted the server, but I'm still getting the same error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (statics.js isn't precompiled)
```

I also tried the following:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )
config.assets.precompile += ('*.css','*.js')
config.assets.precompile += ('.css','.js')
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (statics.js isn't precompiled)
```

These are all suggestions I found on stackoverflow. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have `config.assets.compile = true` in your `config/environments/production.rb`?  If not please add that and try again.

Comment: This fixed it. I neglected to check production.rb. If you turn this into an answer, I will give you credit for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails 3.1.0 ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275636/rails-3-1-0-actionviewtemplateerror-application-css-isnt-precompiled)

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper I'm going to add his comment as an answer, because I found this page and his comment solved my issue. It might help other find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue for me: Go to `config/environments/production.rb` and set `config.assets.compile = true`.