# Wicked_pdf stylesheet not working on Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, pdf, heroku, wicked-pdf

I have a Rails app where I use wicked_pdf to generate PDF's. This is all fine and working locally, but when pushed to heroku the PDF does render, but without applying the stylesheet.

Especially for PDF rendering I have a CSS file: `app/assets/stylesheets/pdf.css.scss`. And in `form.pdf.haml` I load the stylesheet like this:

```
  !!!
  %html{lang: "en", "xml:lang" => "en", xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}
    %head
      %meta{content: "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
      = wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "pdf"
```

As said, it works great locally, but when pushed to heroku, I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No such file or directory - /app/public/pdf.css)
```

What do I have to do to make this work on heroku?

Edit: I found this Gihub repo `https://github.com/jordan-brough/heroku-pdf`, which is an example app for using wicked_pdf on heroku. It really helped by adapting the `environment.rb` to serve a css file from the `public` folder when requesting a PDF.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and it took me a while to crack. I ended up using the [wkhtmltopdf-heroku](https://github.com/rposborne/wkhtmltopdf-heroku) gem and the following setup which works both locally and on heroku in addition to proper handling of the debug option:

In *controller*:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    render pdf: @profile.name + Date.today.to_s(:number),
           background: true,
           encoding: 'utf8',
           :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?
  end
end
```

In *show.pdf.erb*:

```
<% if params[:debug].present? %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'documents' %>
<% else %>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'documents' %>
<% end %>
... rest of view ...
```

In *config/environments/production.rb*:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['documents.css.scss.erb']
```

In *config/initializers/assets.rb*

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( documents.css )
```

Hope that this will be of help to someone.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it for me!

Comment: Incredibly helpful. This should be on wicked_pdf's `README.md`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7278355/1174245) solution and `wicked_pdf` works. But the comment:

> "Activating runtime compilation is not the solution, because of the
>   performance hit we take" @David Tuite

and found answer in [this](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49#issuecomment-24835988) comment with `non-stupid-digest-assets` gem, and works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

There is a GEM for the wkhtmltopdf binaries to work on heroku without you having to install any binaries in your own repository. It also comes packed with the OSX ( darwin ) binary for development. It worked with PDFKit and probably should work with WickedPDF as well

```
https://github.com/bradphelan/wkhtmltopdf-heroku

  or in your Gemfile as
    gem "wkhtmltopdf-heroku"
```

Comment: The binary is not the issue here, it renders a PDF fine, only without the css file. This gem only adds the binary.