# Rails 3.2.13 - application.css isn't precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The error I am getting on the main page is:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

The error I am getting in the log file (log/production.log):

```
ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Reach</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag   "application", media: "all" %>
    6:   <%= requirejs_include_tag "application" %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2601724748379559821_29475380'
```

I have looked at this:
[rails 3.1.0 ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275636/rails-3-1-0-actionviewtemplateerror-application-css-isnt-precompiled)

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

In console it shows:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/rake requirejs:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

**I get the same error**

Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE**

I traced the precompile, this is the results:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:precompile:external (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:test_node (first_time)
** Execute requirejs:test_node
** Execute requirejs:precompile:external
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/rake requirejs:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke requirejs:precompile:all (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:precompile:prepare_source (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:setup (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:precompile:disable_js_compressor (first_time)
** Execute requirejs:precompile:disable_js_compressor
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute requirejs:setup
** Invoke requirejs:clean (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:setup
** Execute requirejs:clean
** Execute requirejs:precompile:prepare_source
** Invoke requirejs:precompile:generate_rjs_driver (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:setup
** Execute requirejs:precompile:generate_rjs_driver
** Invoke requirejs:precompile:run_rjs (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:setup
** Invoke requirejs:test_node (first_time)
** Execute requirejs:test_node
** Execute requirejs:precompile:run_rjs
** Invoke requirejs:precompile:digestify_and_compress (first_time)
** Invoke requirejs:setup
** Execute requirejs:precompile:digestify_and_compress
** Execute requirejs:precompile:all
** Execute assets:precompile
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
** Invoke assets:precompile:nondigest (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:nondigest
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Everything was working, I needed to `touch tmp/restart.txt` to restart Rails after my precompiling.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I realized I didn't mention above, but I am new to RoR. I am adding this here in case anyone runs into the same easy mistake I did.

I had to

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

After precompiling.